# Postgres get next row with different value

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions

I have the following table:

```
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| PersonId |          Role          |  TeamId   |    EffectiveDate    |
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  0001813 | admin                  | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | scrum master           | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | team captain           | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | admin                  | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | scrum master           | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | team captain           | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | delivery lead          | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | product lead           | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | finance partner        | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | individual contributor | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | product lead           | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | finance partner        | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | individual contributor | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | admin                  | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

And I want to get the next effective date for each row. For rows that have the same effective date, I want to grab the next effective date that is greater. In essence, I want to achieve the following result:

```
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| PersonId |          Role          |  TeamId   |    EffectiveDate    |  NextEffectiveDate  |
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  0001813 | admin                  | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | scrum master           | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | team captain           | 005aba1ec | 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
|  0001813 | admin                  | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0001813 | scrum master           | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0001813 | team captain           | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0001813 | delivery lead          | 005aba1ec | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0002817 | product lead           | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | finance partner        | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | individual contributor | 007aba338 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  0002817 | product lead           | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0002817 | finance partner        | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0002817 | individual contributor | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
|  0002817 | admin                  | 007aba338 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
+----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried using the `LEAD` function in Postgres but I don't think the `PARTITION BY` works the way I think it does:

```sql
LEAD(EffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate ORDER BY EffectiveDate) AS NextEffectiveDate
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want `partition by personid`

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0edbf2402a6fa0ccdd850519f92f8853)

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COALESCE (
        MAX("EffectiveDate") OVER 
             (PARTITION BY "PersonId" ORDER BY "EffectiveDate" GROUPS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
        ,
        '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
    )
FROM mytable
```

**PostgreSQL 11** adds the support for `GROUPS` within window functions. This is exactly what it was made for. You want to get always the value of the `EffectiveDate` group. This can be combined with the `PersonId` partition because you want the `GROUPS` functionality only within each person. [Further reading](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/)

Afterwards, the `COALESCE()` function resets the NULL value of the last `GROUPS` result into your default value.

Comment: This looks incredibly useful, unfortunately we're still running on Postgres 9.x I believe. This will be a good excuse to update.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Postgres 11, you can also do this using a window function defined with `range`:

```
MIN(EffectiveDate) OVER
    (PARTITION BY PersonId
     ORDER BY EffectiveDate
     RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1 SECOND' FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS NextEffectiveDate
```

In earlier versions, you can use two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       nullif(max(next_id) over (partition by personid, effectivedate), effectivedate) as next_effectivedate
from (select t.*,
             lead(effectivedate) over (partition by personid order by effectivedate) as next_ed
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: This one throws an error saying `RANGE` can only be used with `UNBOUNDED`

Comment: @Alistair The second one works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b546e711352c0143bf41ba06b8fa3bd1 You just have to add the default value